# Problem with DNS resolution when NOT connected to VPN Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, dns, vpn

When I try to access a website it doesn't work anymore and just tells me "DNS_PROBE_POSSIBLE" unless I am connected to a VPN (Proton VPN) then the internet works fine.

After some digging around I am pretty sure it is a DNS issue but I cannot understand how to fix it.

If I am connected to the VPN and run `systemd-resolve --status | grep Current`
I get:

```
Current Scopes: DNS      
Current DNS Server: 10.16.0.1
Current Scopes: none
Current Scopes: none
Current Scopes: none
```

But if I am not connected to the VPN then when I run the same command I get:

```
 Current Scopes: DNS      
 Current DNS Server: ::1
 Current Scopes: none
 Current Scopes: none
 Current Scopes: none
```

Also I am able to ping 8.8.8.8 but not google.com when not connected to the VPN.
Any advice on how to fix this issue so I can access the internet without a VPN would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you using the ProtonVPN app? If so, some people have said that they need to sign out of the app to restore DNS on their machines, not just disconnect from the VPN.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thank you to @matigo for putting me on track! Turns out it was an issue with ProtonVPN and its new official app.

My guess is: it crashed before I started having these issues, then when trying to reopen it and connect to it, it would throw an unknown error.

So I uninstalled the app using:

```
sudo apt-get autoremove protonvpn
```

but that didn't solve my issue, because **I still had a kill-switch enabled**.

So the solution was to delete all connections with `pvpn-` in their name when showed when running:

```
nmcli connection show --active
```

and deleting them with:

```
nmcli connection delete [connection name]
```

Source: [ProtonVPN support](https://protonvpn.com/support/linux-ubuntu-vpn-setup/)

Comment: I did all this but still, some things don't load if protonVPN is not connected