# Why is Ubuntu 20.04.3 internet access not working?

Tags: networking, server, network-manager, dns, vpn

My Ubuntu OS is connected to the my working internet network, but any internet-reliant services have not been functioning properly. This includes downloading anything (including any packages from the terminal), accessing any websites, and connecting to ProtonVPN.

When I first encountered this problem 2 days ago, connecting to ProtonVPN or changing my DNS IPv4 settings in Ubuntu (not through the terminal)to 8.8.8.8 (Googles DNS) had solved it temporarily. Now, however, neither of these methods are working. The VPN does not connect and changing the DNS settings doesn’t change anything.

As of now, nothing involving the internet works. The internet functions well on all of my other devices, wired and wireless, so it isn’t a problem with the router/modem. I’m genuinely stuck and any help would be appreciated.

Comment: There have been many questions on the site regarding problems with ProtonVPN.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Problem with DNS resolution when NOT connected to VPN Ubuntu 20.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1367637/problem-with-dns-resolution-when-not-connected-to-vpn-ubuntu-20-04)

Answer (score 1):

It turned out to be a problem with how the DNS was routing. Here are the steps I took to diagnose and fix the problem:

1. `ping 8.8.8.8`, which worked fine.
2. `ping www.google.com`, which did *not* work and outputted failure immediately in the terminal.
3. `cd /etc/` through the terminal.
4. I inputted `ls` into the terminal and searched for `resolv.conf` and found that resolv.conf file was corrupted. Whoever is reading this, your file might not be corrupted, so I recommend you do `nano resolv.conf` before taking the drastic measures I did.
5. I don't know if this is safe, but I executed `sudo rm resolv.conf` and then `nano resolv.conf`
6. With the file opened, I added `nameserver 8.8.8.8` to it and saved it.

This fixed my error which turned out to be caused by the file. I suspect ProtonVPN was the culprit, though I can't be sure since the original `resolv.conf` was destroyed.

Comment: In Ubuntu 20.04 `/etc/resolv.conf` is dynamically generated and your edits may be overwritten. Use the command `systemd-resolve --status` to see the system generated status.